# How to put arguments in Swift function?

Tags: ios, swift

I am not familiar with Swift.

I just want to resize an image from file path.

I change the image to UIImage

```
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)
```

and create a function resize the image

```
  func imageWithImage(image:UIImage, scaledToSize newSize:CGSize) -> UIImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0);
    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)))
    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
  }
```

I call the function

```
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)

let resizedImage = imageWithImage(image: UIImage, scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
```

It shows the error

```
Cannot convert value of type UIImage.Type to expected argument type UIImage
```

How to call the function `imageWithImage` ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: let resizedImage = imageWithImage(image: image, scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))

Comment: but it will show another error `Value of optional type 'UIImage?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UIImage' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a very simple fix, you are sending "UIImage" type as a parameter instead of your image variable.

change this line:

```
let resizedImage = imageWithImage(image: UIImage, scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
```

to this:

```
let resizedImage = imageWithImage(image: image, scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
```

Comment: Many thanks, but change the code will show `Value of optional type 'UIImage?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UIImage'`, but It is UIImage, Why I get the error ?

Comment: Thats because the constructor of UIImage from filepath returns an optional value, you could force unwrap it: "image!" but this value could be nil and would end in a crash, so I suggest you unwrap if like this: if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath) { // let resized image....}

Answer (score 1):

you just need to improve your code like below i have improved for you,

```
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)

let resizedImage = imageWithImage(image: image, scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but change the code will show `Value of optional type 'UIImage?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UIImage'`

Comment: You can use "if let" or guard statement to check value can't be nil otherwise in future if you will get filepath nil or wrong then your application must be crash.